# Unable to execute queries on MongoLab via CURL

Tags: curl, mlab

I tried executing a query on Mongolab using CURL to send the HTTP request, but its failing with the error  ***{ "message" : "Please provide a valid API key."}*** . But im using the right API key , using the same key im able to write into the collection on MongoLab but its failing to read back form the same . Here is how i used CURL to achieve the objective

```
curl  'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycoll?q={"2SF5hZcP":{$exists:true}}&fo=true&apiKey=xxxxxxxxx'
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the '{' and '}' characters with their url encoded equivalents (%7b and %7d respectively):

```
curl  'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycoll?q=%7b"2SF5hZcP":%7b$exists:true%7d%7d&fo=true&apiKey=xxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: Hi Guys, How to use it with hard query. like q = {"Filed1" > value}  ?. It's not a Json format.